# Xslt batching records based on repeating tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need create individual xml records, certain tag will indicate the start of new record. My issue is that all tags are on the same level, flat structure.  tag indicates new start of new record
Sample input:

```
 <INO2 >
    <XRI01>
        <MessageType>ITX</MessageType>
        <InterChangePartner>VEWL</InterChangePartner>
        <UpdateProfile>vew</UpdateProfile>
        <WarehouseLocation></WarehouseLocation>
    </XRI01>
    <RFF01>
        <TrafficZone>CU 11111</TrafficZone>
        <Agreement></Agreement>
    </RFF01>
    <NAD01>
        <Qualifier>CA</Qualifier>
        <Consignment>CPH</Consignment>
        <CustomerNo>xxx</CustomerNo>
    </NAD01>
    <NAD01>
        <Qualifier>PW</Qualifier>
        <Consignment>CPX</Consignment>
        <CustomerNo>xxxx</CustomerNo>
    </NAD01>
    <XRI01>
        <MessageType>ITX</MessageType>
        <InterChangePartner>VEWL</InterChangePartner>
        <UpdateProfile>vew</UpdateProfile>
        <WarehouseLocation></WarehouseLocation>
    </XRI01>
    <RFF01>
        <TrafficZone>CU 11112</TrafficZone>
        <Agreement></Agreement>
    </RFF01>
    <NAD01>
        <Qualifier>PK</Qualifier>
        <Consignment>DPX</Consignment>
        <CustomerNo>PX11</CustomerNo>
    </NAD01>
    <NAD01>
        <Qualifier>ZX</Qualifier>
        <Consignment>CPX</Consignment>
        <CustomerNo>ZX12</CustomerNo>
    </NAD01>
</INO2>
```

Desired output: a confirmation for each

```
<Batch>
<Confirmation>
<Header>
<ID>79294</ID>
</Header>
<Parties>
<Party Role="PW"></Party>
<Party Role="CA"></Party>
</Parties>
</Confirmation>
<Confirmation>
<Header>
<ID>79295</ID>
</Header>
<Parties>
<Party Role="PK"></Party>
<Party Role="ZK"></Party>
</Parties>
</Confirmation>
</Batch>
```

My current xslt doesn't give me the desired output for the Parties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
<xsl:template match="/INO2">
    <env:Envelope>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="XRI01"/>
    </env:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="XRI01">
    <Conifrmation>
        <Header>
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(following-sibling::HDR01/InterChangeRef)"/>
            </ID>
        </Header>
        <Parties>
            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::NAD01">
                <xsl:call-template name="Parties">
                    <xsl:with-param name="party">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Qualifier"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Parties>
    </Conifrmation>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Parties">
    <xsl:param name="party"/>
    <xsl:element name="Party">
        <xsl:attribute name="Role">
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::NAD01[Qualifier=$party]/Qualifier"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </element>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Can you fix the input sample to be well-formed XML? As for the XSLT, declare a key `<xsl:key name="group" match="INO2/*[not(self::XRI01)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::XRI01[1])"/>`, then, in the template processing `XRI011`, you can collect the relevant sibling elements for the `XRI01` calling `key('group', generate-id())` and process them as needed

Answer (score 0):

With a key `<xsl:key name="group" match="INO2/*[not(self::XRI01)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::XRI01[1])"/>` to "capture" the sibling elements following your `XRI01` element you can use

```
<xsl:key name="group" match="INO2/*[not(self::XRI01)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::XRI01[1])"/>

<xsl:template match="/INO2">
    <env:Envelope>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="XRI01"/>
    </env:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="XRI01">
    <Conifrmation>
        <xsl:variable name="sibling-group" select="key('group', generate-id())"/>
        <Header>
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($sibling-group/InterChangeRef)"/>
            </ID>
        </Header>
        <Parties>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$sibling-group[self::NAD01]"/>
        </Parties>
    </Conifrmation>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NAD01">
  <Party Role="{Qualifier}"></Party>
</xsl:template>
```

Kind of untested as your input sample is not well formed and doesn't seem complete.

Comment: @Cedas, well, then try to implement it, if you fail, ask a new question showing the details.